# Implementing a trait outside a package that is not part of the source tree

Tags: rust

In a package `cf` lib.rs, this is the code:

```
pub struct CF {
    pub inner: *mut i32,
}

impl Drop for CF {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.inner = &mut 0;
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for CF {}
```

In my project `main.rs` file:

```
use cf::{CF};

pub trait KVDB: Send + Sync {
    fn write(&self) -> String;
}

pub struct DBAndCFs {
    pub cfs: Vec<CF>,
}

pub struct DB {
    pub db: DBAndCFs,
}

impl KVDB for DB {
    fn write(&self) -> String {
        String::from("")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _db = DB {
        db: DBAndCFs{ cfs: Vec::new() },
    };
}
```

This is the compile error:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut i32` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:15:6
   |
15 | impl KVDB for DB {
   |      ^^^^ `*mut i32` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `CF`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `*mut i32`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `CF`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `Unique<CF>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<CF>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Vec<CF>`
note: required because it appears within the type `DBAndCFs`
  --> src/main.rs:7:12
   |
7  | pub struct DBAndCFs {
   |            ^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `DB`
  --> src/main.rs:11:12
   |
11 | pub struct DB {
   |            ^^
note: required by a bound in `KVDB`
  --> src/main.rs:3:24
   |
3  | pub trait KVDB: Send + Sync {
   |                        ^^^^ required by this bound in `KVDB`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `hello_cargo` due to previous error
```

I can fix this by appending in the `lib.rs` file in the `cf` package:

```
unsafe impl Sync for CF {}
```

But let's say that cf package for practicality is already built and published on `crates.io`. I can't add that line to my `main.rs`. So how can I please fix this error? I've tried many things but nothing worked.

EDIT: `cf` is an existing library that I edited here for repro case. If the author has dimmed necessary for it not to be marked as such, then it's not safe to share between threads. From the docs:
`The Sync marker trait indicates that it is safe for the type implementing Sync to be referenced from multiple threads.`

How do I change this since the way I am using it apparently requires this unsafe behaviour? I tried sprinkling `unsafe`s in the code but nothing changed.

EDIT2:

I am using a RwLock to wrap the DB, but still the same error:

```
pub struct DB {
    pub db: RwLock<Option<DBAndCFs>>,
}

impl KVDB for DB {
    fn write(&self) -> String {
        String::from("")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _db = DB {
        db: RwLock::new(Some(DBAndCFs{ cfs: Vec::new() } )),
    };
}
```

So, even if the struct is wrapped with a lock, it's the Trait method that needs to be safe? If so, why marking it unsafe doesn't do the trick?

Comment: Side note, I don't think that `CF` needs to implement `Drop`. Zeroing the stored pointer doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Yes, it's dead code. But that's not changing the err if I remove it!

Comment: If the library author didn't implement `Sync` on this type then there's probably a good reason why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Are you sure you need the `Sync` bound on `KVDB`?

  - If you don't need the `Sync` bound, remove it.
  - If you do need the `Sync` bound, is it truly sound to mark `CF` `Sync`? Carefully read https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html to make sure you don't end up with undefined behavior now or in the future.

    - If it might possibly not be sound, use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or similar, [which only requires `T: Send` for it to implement `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Sync).
    - If you're completely sure it is sound, use a wrapper type and implement `Send`, `Sync`, and `KVDB`, and likely also [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html), on it.

Comment: Do you mean remove it from `pub trait KVDB: Send + Sync`?

Comment: @JohnDifool Yes.

Comment: If I remove `Sync` from KVDB, the code breaks in other places. It's needed.

Comment: @JohnDifool Ok, got it, makes sense. So then try what I said for "If you do need the `Sync` bound".

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate. I am trying to decipher the material you linked. Any examples of this? I am just starting in Rust. :-)

Comment: See my comment under EDIT2 in the OP. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDifool The main reason something wouldn't be `Sync` is if using it from multiple threads simultaneously would cause problems (typically data races). A `Mutex` ensures that only one thread is allowed to use it at once. In contrast, an `RwLock` is designed to allow any number of simultaneous readers or one writer, but it relies on `&` vs `&mut` and [requires `T: Send + Sync` for it to implement `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#impl-Sync). Also, the presence of `unsafe` should only affect cases where the compiler specifically tells you that you need `unsafe`.

Comment: learning something new everyday. What you wrote totally makes sense. I solved my issue just by replacing RwLock with Mutex in the EDIT2.  I guess it's equivalent to using synchronized keyword in Java?

Comment: @JohnDifool Yep, happy to help :) I think [the `synchronized` keyword in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) and Rust's `Mutex` do have similar behavior, only allowing one thread at a time to run using the same synchronization object.